# In PyCharm, when configuring the deployment, is it possible to map files to files (instead of the whole folder)?

Tags: pycharm

As is said in the title, I am configuring the deployment scheme in PyCharm. My project structure is like this:

```
root
|----app1 (folder)
|----manyOtherFolders (folders)
|----core (folder)
|----scheme (file)
|----someOtherFiles (files)
```

I would like to update my `core` and `scheme` to another place automatically. As files and folders in the root can increase in number, I think it is impractical to use excluding-path method. Is there any way to achieve this? Much thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what a "deployment scheme" means?

Comment: @bad_coder It has nothing to do with the file `scheme` in my example). I only use it to mean the total of what we can find in Configuration+Options in the Tools->Deployment menu. (but I struggled to find a term for this)